# NextJS Localization - Changing locate without reloading page

Tags: javascript, next.js, internationalization

I'm trying to add localization to my project and since I'm using nextjs, I've opted to use the default built in localization. The thing is that I'm not a fan of how it does the localization when you are on a dynamic route and would like to ask the masterminds of Stackoverflow to see if there is a solution to this.

See.. There is this site called gamerpay.gg which does exactly what I want. It changes the localization without the page "reloading" and stays on a dynamic route when the localization changes. I know as a fact that they are using nextjs aswell.

So if you visit Gamerpay.gg, you'll see in the upper navbar a localication dropdown. Try it out and see what I mean.

The "reloading" without the actual browser window is at this point of time non important. **The thing that is important would be to fix the dynamic routing with localization**.

Let's get some code:

I am using the built in locale switcher from Nextjs with the Link component:

```
<Link href="" locale="en">
      <a className={styles.flag} id="lang_switcher">
         <Image src="/flags/en.png" height={20} width={20} layout="fixed" />
      </a> 
 </Link>
```

If I am on the root "/" of the page (index). The localization is the most beautiful thing ever made. But! As soon as I jump over to some dynamic routing.. Then I start to become sad.

The Link component above is running on every page inside my footer component. Probably quite important to mention that.

Now, the issue is this: http://localhost:3000/p/4829/
If I visit that url normally, then everything is working correctly. But if I scroll down to the footer and press the Link component to change language, then the url becomes http://localhost:3000/en/p/[post_id]/

For what I can see on their official documents then there is no "easy fix" for this. I would have to do some trickery. This is why I ask you, the Stackoverflow community, to see if there is a better option on how to keep the url / not break the url by using the localization button.

!Woop Woop!

===
UPDATE ===========================

Aight, so. I've investigated the nextjs router and I've found a "asPath" object inside of that. If I add that "router.asPath" to my href, then I am able to remain on the correct page while translation does happend. I will not mark this as my answer until I've tested it for some time. :D

```
<Link href={router.asPath} locale="en">
    <a className={styles.flag} id="lang_switcher">
        <Image src="/flags/en.png" height={20} width={20} layout="fixed" />
    </a> 
</Link>
```

Comment: There is section in NextJs for Dynamic routing, what have you tried from that so far?

Comment: @Soheb well basically nothing at the moment other than reading stuff online. I have this: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-route-has-dynamic-segments But if possible, I would like to not do this part as the localization is running in the footer which makes me unable to define the **href** as the example is showing. I need something dynamic that works with all pages inside my app.

Comment: If the idea is to use the current path but only change the locale through `Link` then using `router.asPath` as the `href` value is the right approach. You should add the solution you found as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I've been testing and as one of you suggested, I should post the answer (i forgot, sorry haha).

The solution was indeed to use asPath. Works smoothly.

```
<Link href={router.asPath} locale="en">
    <a className={styles.flag} id="lang_switcher">
        <Image src="/flags/en.png" height={20} width={20} layout="fixed" />
    </a> 
</Link>
```